# Why does a lagplot exhibits pattern when data is non-random?

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, intuition

I recently started learning forecasting and I came across lagplots, which is used to test whether a given set of data is random or not.

Although, I understand how to use the plots, I don't get an intuitive understanding of why there is a pattern that is exhibited when the data is not random.

Comment: Isn't having patterns essentially the same thing as being non-random?

Comment: My question is "Why should it exhibit a pattern? Why can't a lag plot of a non-random data be random? In other words what makes the plot Y(i) vs Y(i-k) patterned for a non-random data?"

Comment: Why, of course it can _appear_ random if your dataset is crafted for that purpose.